# Issue with sqlite3 driver on Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite

I have an ItemsControl inside a map control in WPF. The TilesSource Class has been modified to retrieve tiles from a custom location inside the PC. Here is the code of the map:

```c#
<maps:Map Name="Map" 
          ZoomLevel="14" 
          Center="23.129, -82.38" 
          Grid.RowSpan="2">
          <maps:Map.Children>
             <vm:CustomTileLayer/>
                <maps:MapItemsControl
                x:Name="PlacesLayer"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Places}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource genericPushpinContentTemplate}"
                Visibility="{Binding Places.Enabled}"/>
                ...
<maps:Map/>
```

This collection is properly created and the data in it is correct, the item template code is this one:

```c#
<DataTemplate x:Key="genericPushpinContentTemplate">
    <maps:Pushpin maps:MapLayer.Position="{Binding Location}"
                  Tag="{Binding}"
                  MouseDown="ShowContentPopup">
                  <maps:Pushpin.Content>
                      <Grid>
                          <Image Source="{Binding PinImage}"/>
                      </Grid>
                  </maps:Pushpin.Content>
    </maps:Pushpin>
</DataTemplate>
```

The problem is that this is correctly generated on the pc i am working, on Windows 7 sp1, with Visual Studio 2012 installed and also .net framework 4.0 and 4.5 compact, also in a computer with Windows 8.0. But in a number of other computers with windows 8.0 the content does not display the pushpins in the map, i need help figuring out what might be wrong here, if it is a .net framework issue or a OS issue or a dll issue, i'm using the Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.dll ver 1.0.0.

-------------EDIT-----------------

So i found out what was wrong, the problem is that i was fetching the data from a **sqlite3** database, and on windows seven the values were wrong, the coma was of by two positions, on the coordinates, but on the other systems i tried, the reading was correct and therefore, the pins were'nt displayed correctly. Now the question is why did this happens and if there is a way instead of my ugly patch, to fix it.